# Can synthetic division be used to divide $8x^{5}-4x^{4}+6x^{3}-11x^{2}-2x+3$ by $\left(x^{2}-\frac{1}{4}\right)$?

Tags: polynomials

This is a peculiar case because a difference of two squares is a factor so if I perform synthetic division with each factor "separately" ie $\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)$, then I get two distinct polynomials. Now I am not sure what to do with the two to get the final answer. Do I add, subtract, multiply, divide them?

Comment: Why don't you just divide by the quadratic in the first place?

Comment: What Fenris commented.  Also, **first** clear the $(1/4)$ fraction by multiplying both the dividend and the divisor by $4$.  This will make it easier on you.

Comment: If you *really* want to use synthetic division, there is a method for dividing by a general quadratic divisor on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division#For_non-monic_divisors). If you're not bothered, you can always divide by $x - 1/2$ and then by $x + 1/2$.

Comment: To use regular synthetic division, Divide by one term first, then divide that divisor with the second term.

Comment: Notice that $f(1) = 0$, therefore $x - 1$ is also a factor for this particular problem.

Comment: @Fenris yes but you cannot synthetic divide with a quadratic (at least without adjustments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply may ‘compose’ the two synthetic divisions:
$$\begin{array}{*7{r}}
&8&-4&6&-11&-2&3 \\\times\tfrac12&&4&0&3&-4&-3\\\hline
&\color{red}8&\color{red}0&\color{red}6&\color{red}{-8}&\color{red}{-6}&\color{cyan}0 \\
\times-\tfrac12&&-4 &2&-4&6 \\\hline
& \color{red}8 &\color{red}{-4}&\color{red}8&\color{red}{-12}& \color{cyan}0
\end{array},$$
whence the quotient $\:8x^3-4x^2+8x-12$.

Comment: *Elève Bernard ! Au tableau !* So long time I did not see such a thing ! Even for me, playing with the colors explains very well. Cheers and take care :-)

Comment: Il faut dire que j'ai pas mal pratiqué la méthode de Horner pour l'évaluation des polynômes.

Comment: Merci! I don't know why I didn't think of this

Comment: Also, What is Horner's method for polynomials? When I search it up only synthetic division comes up, and the thing about nested x's

Comment: @user71207: It is the method used to minimise the number of operations in evaluating a polynomial, by using nested parentheses, e.g. $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=\bigl((ax+b)x+c\bigr)x+d$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)$ be the given polynomial. Multiplying top and bottom by $4$, we get:

$$\frac{32x^{5}-16x^{4}+24x^{3}-44x^{2}-8x+12}{4x^2-1}$$

Now $f(1/2) = f(-1/2) = 0$, so we have no remainder, which means the quotient is a cubic polynomial, $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$. Therefore:

$$(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)(4x^2 - 1) = 32x^{5}-16x^{4}+24x^{3}-44x^{2}-8x+12$$

Comparing the $x^5$ term and the constant term on the RHS, we have that $4a = 32, a = 8$, and $-d = 12, d= -12$, as there is only one way to make these terms.

Now comparing the $x^4$ term, $a \cdot 0 + b \cdot 4 = -16$, so $b = -4$. With the $x$ term, $c \cdot -1 + d \cdot 0 = -8$, thus $c = 8$.

Therefore the quotient is $8x^3-4x^2+8x-12$.

Comment: Thanks for this! A different approah

Comment: No problem, not at all!